# facebook login takes long time during logging in

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have used facebook sdk 3.5 in android to create custom login button after clicking will get facebook details then send to server and then go to next intent(screen).I have created the code below and using it but the progress dialog  takes long time to get to onCompletemethod() in facebook also sometime its timedOut.I have posted the code below please let me know if there is a better way to login than the one below  and if I can reduce the time it takes to login facebook .I really appreciate ay help .Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    static  String email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Wait...");

        Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressDialog.show();

                    }
                });

                Session.openActiveSession(MainActivity.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                    // callback when session changes state
                    @Override
                    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                        if (session.isOpened()) {

                            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                                    if (user != null) {

                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    email=   (String) response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email");
                        Log.d("email", email);

                                        new FetchTask().execute();

                    }
                                }
                            }).executeAsync();

                    }
                    }
                });




            }});
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(Session.getActiveSession() != null)
        {
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(MainActivity.this, requestCode, resultCode, data);


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Maybe you found a solution. 
I have the problem on Nexus 4 , but not get it on Samsung S3

Sorry I have no as much reputation to leave a comment.